# Problema com DLL

Tags: c++

Olá amigos sou iniciante em c++.

como posso impedir as pessoas de injetar uma dll no meu programa?
eles colocam uma dll com o nome IPHLPAPI na pasta de meu programa, então essa dll intrusa é carregada.

eu tentei fazer com que o programa feche quando essa dll intrusa fosse carregada, mas como meu programa usa a IPHLPAPI.DLL nativa do windows, então meu programa acaba fechando mesmo sem a dll intrusa.

Comment: As duas tem o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: olá, tamanhos diferentes, existe alguma forma de eu resolver isso usando o tamanho como restrição?

Comment: Creio que exista alguma forma de diferenciar os tamanhos e você pode fazer o controle por ai

Answer (score 0):

Se as pessoas estão colocando para carregar no programa, isso é por quê no computador delas essa dll está em falta. Indico inicializar um download de att do NetFrameWork C++(Não sei qual é a versão, mas chuto que é a de 2015 por quê o Windows 10 está em falta de muitas dll's) assim o windows vai jogar essa dll no pasta padrão dela e tu será executado sem esbarrar um no outro.

Quanto a como o comando de att do NetFrameWorkC++, procura na internet como isso acontece no prompt, depois só adiciona a um código system do seu programa, para ficar automatizado.

Espero ter te ajudado...